# Create stored procedure to load text file into SQL database with predetermined offset values and create insert

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, substring, bulkinsert

I have the following 3 records stored in a text file...

But the SQL script will need to process 4.1 million records in good time...

```
//Instruction:
Copy this to a text file named: Deceased.txt

000101001118 IDENTITY NUMBER NOT NUMERIC
0001010061181PERSON DECEASED                            19990101OBSTRUCTIVE AIRWAYS SYNDROME                      BABA                                         NOWEZILE
0001010077097                                                                                                     COERTZEN                                     AZIL CUBITT JONO
```

-> I need to write a query could be function / stored procedure that does the following:

1. Takes each record and copies to a sql table.

The table will have the following columns:

```
National_id   Errmsg   DeceasedDTE   DeceasedReason  Surname FirstNames 
First_Initial Second_Initial Third_Initial FName1 FName2 FName3
```

Herewith the offset values for only the first 6 columns...

```
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],1,13)) --National_id
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],14,43)) --Errmsg
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],57,8))  --DeceasedDTE    
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],65,50)) --DeceasedReason 
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],115,45)) --Surname   
  ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING([TABLE],158,50)) --FirstNames
```

Notes I need to use the `FirstNames` column to help populate the remaining columns..

Also the `FirstNames` is separated with a space and I need them spit up into each FName1, FName2 and FName3 ... with its corresponding first letter that makes up the initial..

1. I then need to create a script send to a .txt file that creates an insert statement for each record with the following columns... national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name

E.G.

```
Set @Insert = "insert into prodmgr.t_unverified (national_id, surname, First_Initial, Second_Initial,Third_Initial, First_Name, Second_Name, Third_Name) values ('"
```

I used Bulk insert to make this process more efficient ... but not successful as yet... the script will need to process millions of records..

Please help :)

Comment: Sorry about that... SQL Server 2012

Comment: Is anyone looking at this? :)